# YUP email allows non ascii characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, yup

I am using YUP librarys string().email() method to test for email. However it allows me to enter non-ascii characters.

```
Yup.string().email().validate("abc@example.com") // valid
Yup.string().email().validate("abc@example") // invalid
Yup.string().email().validate("abčš@example.com") // valid
```

I checked YUP implementation and they are using regex

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

What is interesting though, that testing on regex101.com with provided regular expression I get these results

```
"abc@example.com" // valid
"abc@example" // valid
"abčš@example.com" // invalid
```

Why is there are difference (I am using React with YUP) between JS and Regex101?

I want to disallow non ascii characters (which works in regex101 with yup's regex) and make domain required (which is actually already working with yup even though have different behavior in regex101).